# How to exclude keys from a map and display only the values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, object

I have an `Object` `obj` as below:

```
const obj = {
         Hostname: "abc"
         id: 189883
         message: "error message"
         name: "script name"
};
```

1. I want to exclude the key `Hostname` and it value.
2. I only want to capture the `values` excluding `keys` such that the output looks as below:
   `189883:error message:script name`

The final output should be a `string`.
I have written the following code but it is creating array element for every letter

```
const resultObj = Object.values(vascoResponse.rows[0]obj).map((row) =>
  Object.values(row).filter((val) => val)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.values()`

```js
const objec = {
  Hostname: "abc",
  id: 189883,
  message: "error message",
  name: "script name"
};
res = Object.values(objec).filter((o,i) => o != "abc" ).join(":")
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could grab the entries of your object to obtain an array of `[[key, value], [key2, value2], ...]` pairs. Then you can use `.filter()` on it to remove the pair with a key of `"Hostname"`. Lastly, you can map each inner array to its value and use `.join(":")` to obtain a string:

```js
const obj = {
   Hostname: "abc",
   id: 189883,
   message: "error message",
   name: "script name"
};

const res = Object.entries(obj)
             .filter(([key]) => key !== "Hostname")
             .map(([,v]) => v).join(":");

console.log(res);
```

If you need this functionality to be extracted into a function, you could destructure the object argument to obtain all keys/value excluding the `Hostname`, and then grab and join the values based on that:

```js
const obj = {
   Hostname: "abc",
   id: 189883,
   message: "error message",
   name: "script name"
};

const getString = ({Hostname, ...r}) => Object.values(r).join(':');
console.log(getString(obj));
```

Comment: You could even take it one step further by  running it as an IIFE: `console.log((({Hostname, ...r}) => Object.values(r).join(':'))(obj))` ;-)

Comment: @cars10m haha, you're right . You could even use the comma operator: `({Hostname, ...r} = obj, Object.values(r).join(','))`, but this adds variables to the global scope and won't work in strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

So I see where you're going with this, but I'd personally avoid `Object.values()` altogether. As a general rule when deciding what to do with an array, I try to ask these questions:

- Do I want to extract a subset of values from an object based on keys? -> use `Object.keys()` to filter
- Do I want to extract a subset of values from an object based on values? -> use `Object.values()`
- Do I want to turn one array into another of equal length? -> use `array.map()`
- Do I want to turn one array into a shorter array? -> use `array.filter()`
- Do I want to turn an array into a single value like a string? -> use `array.reduce()`

Since you want a subset of values from the Object, based on the keys and you want to turn it into a string, then we should probably use `Object.keys()`, `array.filter()`, and then `array.reduce()` like this:

```js
let obj = {
   Hostname: "abc",
   id: 189883,
   message: "error message",
   name: "script name"
};

let resultString = Object.keys(obj) //gets an array of keys from the object
  .filter(key => key != "Hostname") //removes 'Hostname' from the array
  .reduce((accumulator, key) => 
    accumulator == "" ? accumulator + obj[key] : accumulator + ":" + obj[key],
   "");

console.log(resultString);
```

If you run that code snippit you'll find that it outputs a string exactly like you were hoping for every time. The ternary operator inside the reducer is just a sneaky way of adding the ":" colon character before every new value unless it's the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
     Hostname: "abc",
     id: 189883,
     message: "error message",
     name: "script name"
};

let str=Object.entries(obj)
 .filter(([k])=>k!=="Hostname")
 .map(([k,v])=>v).join(":");
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` and `Object.values`.

```js
delete obj["Hostname"];
Object.values(obj).join(":");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'id' && key !== 'Hostname'))
```

```js
let obj = {
  Hostname: "abc",
  id: 189883,
  message: "error message",
  name: "script name"
};

obj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'id' && key !== 'Hostname'))

console.log(obj)
```